# When am I able to upgrade my inventory and ammo capacity?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the previous game, you were generally were able to upgrade your inventory and ammo capacities at specific points in the game.

Helping a claptrap in an area usually rewarded you with a backpack upgrade and you could upgrade your ammo capacities at the nearest ammo dump if you have the money.

However so far in Borderlands 2, I haven't found a claptrap that needed rescuing and the ammo dumps only carry spare ammo.  I keep running out of inventory space very quickly and am constantly running out of ammo in heavy firefights which is getting irritating.  I have plenty of money, but not enough carrying capacity.

**At what points am I able to upgrade my inventory capacity and my ammo capacity?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ammo and backpack upgrades are acquired on the black market. These purchases have to be made with Eridium; a sought after mineral on Pandora. Once you reach the city of 'Sanctuary', one of the first missions you encounter is entitled 'Plan B'. You will receive 4 Eridium from Scooter, allowing you to make your first purchase at 'Earl's black Market'.

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Eridium

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also note that despite what you might expect, there's no extra upgrades you can unlock in playthrough 2

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade through Crazy Earl with Eriduim. I am currently maxed out at a 27 space backpack.  The upgrade costs are set at 4, 8, 12, 16, and 20.

Comment: I would assume you can get another set of upgrades in play through 2, but I am not there yet.

Comment: Sorry, dude.  Didn't see your edit in the queue. ><

Comment: @Kexlox nope, you don't

Comment: Upgrade costs start at 4 and go up by 4 each time, up to 20. That is, your list is missing “12”…