# Where can I spend Eridium?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just found some Eridium, and thanks to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/where-can-i-find-more-eridium) I have some leads on how to find more.  The pop up says it can be spent at the "Black Market".  Is that a literal or figurative place?  How do I get there?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84825/when-am-i-able-to-upgrade-my-inventory-and-ammo-capacity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can spend Eridium once you get to Sanctuary.  Crazy Earl runs the black market. It's not hidden or anything: it's just one of the stores available in town.

Once you've bought everything from Crazy Earl; there is a boss monster, Terramorphous, that will cost 4 Eridium to fight again.  ([source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/108dsi/so_now_what_should_i_do_w_eridium/))

Comment: I believe the store is also only open at night. At least I've noticed on a couple of occasions that the store wasn't available... and both times it was during the daylight.

Comment: @user33466 Are you sure you went to the right (purple, very purple) door? There's a closed door right next to his shop, but he's always been open for me.

Comment: @Ben Brocka - same for me, always open.  Can't say I ever noticed the time of day.

Comment: Just checked, it was night time and he was there.

Comment: The location of Crazy Earl is near the side entrance to Moxxi's (The exit nearest the slot machines to the left of the bar when talking to Moxxi). Crazy Earl is available regardless of Daytime or Nighttime.